# How to peek a record using name rather then using id in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

So in rails we could find a record by name, id etc, similarly i want to do in ember without making a server request
I have a model called person{id, name}. If i want to peek a record by id i do this:

```
this.get('store').peekRecord('person', id)
```

which gives me the record based on id, but now i want to peek a record with a particular name, i tried something like this:

```
this.get('store').peekRecord('person', {name: "testname"})
```

which dose not seem to work.
i need a way peek a record using just the name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only peekRecord using the unique identifier for the model, which is `id` property. If you do want to make a request then `queryRecord` is what you want. but you don't want to make a request so the only choice is peekAll and filter the result,

```
let allRecord = this.get('store').peekAll('person');
let filteredResult = allRecord.filterBy('name','testname');
//filteredResult is an array of matching records
```